# SQL DB Deployment

Tags: sql, winforms, installation

The scenario:

I have written a software application that includes an installer, that is to be used by Mr Layman to install the system on to a single computer.

The system is a simple C# winforms application with an SQL Express database.  The target machine would be a standard installation of Windows XP with SQL Express and .NET 3.5 installed.

I am able to create the installer for the winforms app, that would check the version, create all the directories and copy over all the necessary executable's etc.  I have also an SQL script that will create the database and populate it with the necessary data.  However I do not know how to go about creating a stand alone installer for the database on the target machine.

I have an SQL script that will create the database etc, but how do I make the installer run this script?  I've had a google and I don't really know what I'm looking for, can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't already have a RDBMS in mind, then you might want to consider SQLite (http://sqlite.org/).  It's lightweight and performs well (as long as you're not doing "big data" stuff with it), and there's no fiddly setup required.

Comment: Can you not just embed the db as a mdf file in your project and deploy that way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action in the installer project that will take your SQL script and run it against the database. Here's an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk.aspx) that covers the basics.

Answer (score 0):

An installer which runs SQL scripts can be created in 2 ways:

The very hard way:

- create an installation with custom dialogs which retrieve the SQL connection information
- save that information somehow (in an MSI package you can use installer properties)
- write a custom action which uses that information to connect to SQL Server and run your script

The easy way:

- use a setup authoring tool which supports SQL scripts

If you want a free solution, I recommend [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net). It has a steep learning curve, but it does what you need.